# Why is my ajax content not being indexed by google

Tags: ajax, seo, google-crawlers

I have tried to set my site up ( http://www.diablo3values.com )according to the guidelines set out here : https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/  However, it appears that Google has updated their indexes (because I see the revisions to the meta description tags) but the ajax content does not show up in the index.

I am trying to use the “Handle pages without hash fragments” option.

If you view either of the following:

http://www.diablo3values.com/?_escaped_fragment_=

http://www.diablo3values.com/about?_escaped_fragment_=

you will correctly see the HTML snap shot with my content. (those are the two pages I an most concerned about).

Any Ideas?  Am I doing something wrong? How do you get google to correclty recognize the  tag.

Answer (score 7):

I'm typing this as an answer, since it got a little to long to be a comment.

First of all, your links seems to point to `localhost:8080/about`, and not `/about`, which probably is why google doesn't index it in the first place.

Second, here's my experience with pushstate urls and Google AJAX crawling:

My experience is that ajax crawling with pushstate urls is handled a little differently by google than with hashbang urls. Since google won't know that your url is a pushstate url (since it looks just like a regular url), you need to add `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to all your pages, not only the "root" page. And google doesn't seem to know that the pages are part of the same application, so it treats every page as a separate Ajax application. So the Google bot will never actually create a navigation structure inside `_escaped_fragment_`, like `_escaped_fragment_=/about`, as it would with a hashbang url (`#!/about`). Instead, it will request `/about?_escaped_fragment_=` (which you aparently already have set up). This goes for all your "deep links". Instead of `/?_escaped_fragment_=/thelink`, google will always request `/thelink?_escaped_fragment_=`.

But as said initially, the reason it doesn't work for you is probably because you have `localhost:8080` urls in your `_escaped_fragment_` generated html.

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot only knows to crawl the escaped fragment if your urls conform to the hash bang standard.  As users navigate your site, your urls need to be:

```
http://www.diablo3values.com/
http://www.diablo3values.com/#!contact
http://www.diablo3values.com/#!about
```

Googlebot actually needs to see these urls in the source code so that it can follow them.  Then it knows to download the following urls:

```
http://www.diablo3values.com/?_escaped_fragment=contact
http://www.diablo3values.com/?_escaped_fragment=about
```

On your site you appear to be loading a new page on each click, and then loading the content of each page via AJAX too.  This is not how I would expect an AJAX site to work.  Usually the purpose of using AJAX is so that the user never has to load a whole new page.  When the user clicks, the new content section is loaded and inserted into the page.  You serve the navigation *once* and then you only serve escaped fragments of the content.

Comment: Stephen, Thanks for taking a look. I am trying to use the newer HTML5 pushstate rather than the hashbang standard (hopefully the page is not re-downloading with each link).  I am using a backbone.js router that is supposed to fallback to the hashbang if the browser does not support it.   The documentation by google leads me to believe this can still be done (look at step three of https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: Having said all that I think you helped me spot my error:  

I was using: (http://www.diablo3values.com/about?_escaped_fragment_=) 
not:  (http://www.diablo3values.com/about?_escaped_fragment=about)

Do you think that might be it?

Comment: If you use push state your server has to return full pages to googlebot when the url is requested.  Googlebot only fetches the _escaped_fragment when there are hashbang urls.  You need to #include (server side) the escaped fragments into the text of the page for first page view, and then use fetch partial escaped fragments and use pushstate for clicks.

Comment: I thought that you could get around the #! requirement by include the escaped fragment meta tag <meta name="fragment" content="!">